Regarding the Process of Determining a Singularity is Removable
I am having trouble consistently identifying when a singularity of a complex-valued function is removable. As I understand it, the most common way is to show that the function extends to a holomorphic function in the deleted neighborhood of the singularity, i.e., to show that the function is bounded in the deleted neighborhood of the singularity. The way I've generally been approaching this is via power-series expansions and then factorization to find the analytic continuation on the deleted neighborhood. Another way I have found out is by comparing the order of the zeros of the denominator and numerator if it's applicable. For example, given the function $$f(z)=\frac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1-\sin(\pi z/2)} $$
I know that the singularities occur at $z\in\{1+4n|n\in\mathbb{Z} \}$. Comparing the order of the zero of $(z+3)$ and to the order of $1-\sin(\pi z/2)$, we see they are both simple, so $z=-3$ is a removable singularity. However, the solution to the problem also says that $z=1$ is removable. I am having trouble understanding why, since the order of $z=1$ is 2. My approach has been to observe that
$$f(z) = \frac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1-\sin(\pi z/2)}=\frac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(z-1)-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{\pi^3}{8}(z-1)^3+\cdots \right)}=\frac{(z-1)^2(z+3)}{1-\frac{\pi}{2}(z-1)\left(1-\frac{1}{3!}\frac{\pi^2}{4}(z-1)^2+\cdots \right)} $$
If the $1$ weren't floating in the denominator, then one of the $(z-1)$ would cancel on top, and I could see how the order of the zeros match, but this won't work since if I factor it out then we will have $1/(z-1)$ in the denominator. So how can I see that $z=1$ is a removable singularity, without turning to taking limits, i.e., is this possible with Taylor expansion.

$1-\sin(\pi z/2) = 1-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} (z-1))$. The latter might be easier to develop into a series in powers of $z-1$.

Thanks for your response. However, based on this, does that mean that I didn't need to expand about z=1 in the first place, since that equation follows just from the identity $\sin x = \cos(-\pi/2 +x)$?

Your Taylor series for the denominator seems incorrect. The Taylor series at $z=1$ should begin with a quadratic term, namely $c_2(z-1)^2+\cdots$ for some number $c_2$.

Hint: Your series expansion is not correct. Expanding $\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}z\right)$ at $z=1$ you can start with
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}z\right)}=1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}(z-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
and expand using an addition theorem to get
\begin{align*}
1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}(z-1)+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
&=1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}(z-1)\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{2}(z-1)\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
&=1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{2}(z-1)\right)\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}\,\frac{\pi^2}{4}(z-1)^2+\cdots\right)\\
&\color{blue}{=(z-1)^2\left(\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\cdots\right)}\end{align*}
which corresponds to @TorstenSchoeneberg's comment.
Now you can conclude that $f$ has at $z=1$ a removable singularity
of order two.
